# How to include infographics and pdf file generation in PHP Website

Tags: php, pdf, web-applications, graphics

i would like to include dynamic graphs as summary of information in webpage and pdf report generation.

What are the options available?Which are easy to implement and learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDF generation, you can use FPDF:

http://www.fpdf.org/

For dynamic graphs... I assume you want something in Javascript. These are pretty good options:

- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- Some more [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/) and [here](http://smashfreakz.com/2012/07/jquery-graphs-and-charts-plugin/)